# how the break command acts in my test code

Tags: c, break

my test code is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    char c;
    while ((c=getchar())!=EOF){
            if(c>='A'&& c<='Z'){
                    c=c-'A'+'a';
                    putchar(c);
            }
            //else break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

without the else break command, the while loop went forever, but when I added the "else" command line, the loop only executed for once, I typed "A" it displayed "a" on the monitor and then stopped. But I thought it should be like this: if A~Z is input, then it produces the lower case letter, if the input character is not within the range, eg. a number of something, it would break the loop and execution would stop. Where am I made the mistake? I have tried to add curly brackets after "else" around "break", but the result remained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `getchar` function will read EVERY char from stdin, even the newline character from the "Enter/Return" key.

When you enable your `else` part, your code also reacts to the `'\n'`, which causes the break.

You may try to change the

```
else break;
```

by

```
else if (c != '\n') break;
```

in your code.

Comment: Yes! Thank you very much, it really works! I'd like to up vote your reply but I don't have enough reputation! Many thanks to you!

Answer (score 0):

```
char c;
while ((c=getchar())!=EOF){
```

needs to be

```
int c;
while ((c=getchar())!=EOF){
```

see http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_getchar.htm

IN addition your code does not say 'stop if they enter a char thats not A-Z', it says' ask them for input till they type EOF - echoing back to them when they type A-Z'. EOF is types as ctrl-D on UNix

Comment: I have just changed the type from char to int, compile .c file and executed it, but it still didn't work. The example in the link also uses char c and c=getchar() in the function despite it says the declaration of getchar() is as: int get char(void).

Comment: it is terrible that that sample uses char ;-(. But char c can never == EOF, thats why u need int

Comment: @Schawn Your "example in the link" is bad code, like much of the C code that you can find on the Internet. You can ask a separate question on why it's bad (it probably causes the infinite loop).

Answer (score 0):

If you enter only `A` and nothing else, your program sees `A` and the newline character `\n`. The newline character doesn't match the pattern `A...Z`, so the `break` statement is executed.

You can see this by printing the code of the character:

```
while ((c=getchar())!=EOF){
    printf("Character code: %d\n", c);
    ...
}
```

You can enter something like `ABACABB` to see your desired behavior.

Comment: I think you're right, then I revised my code as: while(){if(&&) printf("lower case character: %c\n",c); if(c=='\n'||c=='\r') printf("enter new c"); else break;}. However, the "enter new c" never shows up?